# What is <extend> used for in Magento 1.x EE?

Tags: layout, blocks, layout-update

#### Source: Magento Enterprise Edition User Guide, Version 1.14.2.1

#### Page: 660

I've researched quite a bit on the tag function but have not seen any real world examples of its usage. At first glance it seemed to be a cleaner method of unsetting and inserting a child block by updating the parent but because the doc has been sparse on the tag description its actual behavior is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea might have been to query the original node and pass the aforementioned `extend` node to [Varien_Simplexml_Element::extend()](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php#L374), accompanied by moving the original node to a different parent node in the merged layout XML.

I could not find any core code in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout*` that reacts on `extend` elements though (opposed to [`block`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L204), [`reference`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L209), [`action`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L213), and [`remove`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L154) from the same chapter). So I guess this type of layout update somehow found its way into the documentation, but not actually into any release.

Comment: I plan on marking this as the correct answer as it was what was thought originally but I am leaving it open for 48 more hours to allow the chance for another who may have more insight to magento dev to possibly have another answer. But I suspect it was an unimplemented tag method also as I can't get it to fire in any manner at this point but will have time for testing tonight.